# JQuery/JSON Error - [AJAX] Invalid JSON - Server reponse is:

Tags: jquery

I was trying a Jquery/Json terminal thing: http://terminal.jcubic.pl

I uploaded to my website and tried an example and I get the following error message;

```
login: demo
password: ****
[AJAX] Invalid JSON - Server reponse is: 
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  require(json-rpc/json-rpc.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in <b>/home/u262905308/public_html/examples/json-rpc-service-demo.php</b> on line <b>3</b><br
 />
<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  require(): Failed opening required 'json-rpc/json- rpc.php' (include_path='.:/opt/php-5.5/pear') in <b>/home/u262905308    /public_html/examples/json-rpc-service-demo.php</b> 
on line <b>3</b><br />
```

Comment: Looks like you haven't got json-rpc installed - or that space (`json- rpc.php`) shouldn't be there.

Comment: I see, so how would one install the Json-rpc so to speak. It's in the directory, same one as this.

Comment: If it's in the same folder, then maybe you want to `require(json-rpc.php)` instead?

Comment: EDIT: I looked again and found a "Json-rpc" folder with nothing in. What would I put in here? Sorry I'm a noob at coding, etc. The folders in that directory are: https://gyazo.com/b8844d202c7cf0b4f2bb2fdcbffb3d0d

Comment: It looks to me like your script is expecting the json-rpc.php file to be in that folder.

Comment: Further edit, there is a "Jsson-rpc.php" file and folder. Should I put it into the folder? Is that where is it looking to call it from? Wrote this message before I refreshed and saw yours, exactly what I was thinking...

Comment: I got another error message, although we may be getting there:                                                                                                            [AJAX] Invalid JSON - Server reponse is: 
    <br />
    <b>Warning</b>:  get_object_vars() expects parameter 1 to be   object, string given in <b>/home/u262905308/public_html/examples  /json-rpc/json-rpc.php<
    /b> on line <b>75</b><br />
    {"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":null,"id":"2","error":{"code":-  32600,"message":"Invalid Request: no method"}}

Comment: You might want to try and print the data that your client is sending to the server, and check that it looks right.

Comment: So, how would I print the data?